# how to save my QR generated image into gallery? using Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, dart-pub

I am trying to generate an image using `RenderRepaintBoundary` and want to save the image in my local directory.
I am able to save the image but I get a black image instead of a QR image.

**Code block where I am writing the image to the directory:**

```
try {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =  
        globalKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();  
    var image = await boundary.toImage();
    
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ImageByteFormat.png);
    
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();
         
    final file =
              await new File('/<localpath>/image.png').create();
          
    await file.writeAsBytes(pngBytes);
} catch (e) {
    print(e);    
}
```

**Code block where QR code is being generated:**

```
RepaintBoundary( key: globalKey,child: QrImage(data: _dataString,size: 0.3 * bodyHeight,), );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is caused by having transparent background;
Simple solution is to wrap your QrImage with Container that has white backround:

```
Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: QrImage(....
)
```

Comment: You saved me a lot of time. THANKS.